# Name and explanation for this product of representations

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I'm just starting a course in representation theory. I have been told that for $G$ a group, $\theta$ a $1$-dimensional representation of $G$, and another representation $\rho: G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ of $G$, we can define

$\theta \otimes \rho: G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ given by $\theta \otimes \rho(g)=\theta(g) \cdot \rho(g)$.

I have a few questions:

- Does this "product of representations" have a name?
- What exactly is the $\cdot$ in $\theta(g) \cdot \rho(g)$? Unless there is a typo in what I have been given, if $\theta: G \to \mathrm{GL}(W)$ need not have $W$ related to $V$ or anything, so how do we define a product between an element of $\mathrm{GL}(W)$ and another in $\mathrm{GL}(V)$? Since $\mathrm{Im}( \theta \otimes \rho) \subseteq \mathrm{GL}(V)$, and $\theta$ is a one-dimensional representation, do we require $W \subseteq V$ then? I can see algebraically that $\theta \otimes \rho$ is a homomorphism, I just don't really understand what objects I am doing algebra on here.

Comment: This is (a special case of) the tensor product representation.  The $\cdot$ here is because $\theta$ is one-dimensional so $\lambda\otimes(-)$  has the same effect as usual multiplication by element $\lambda\cdot(-)$, $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}$ ($GL_1(\mathbb{F})=\mathbb{F}^\times$).

Comment: When I learned representation theory I was given this construction first (in an exercise, before we even knew what tensor products of vector spaces were!), and then a while later (around the $11$th lecture) I was given the general construction for arbitrary representations. So likely this is intended as a little teaser/foreshadowing, and it will all be explained in due course. Or you could try reading ahead in the notes :-).

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun You are being overly pedantic. This question is not too broad.